# rTorrent pauses magnet links download after getting meta information

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent, magnet-links

As the title says when I try to download magnet links with rtorrent it gets the meta information and then it pauses the torrent. I have to resume the torrent again with CTRL+S every time.
The OS is CentOS 6 but I had this problem in Debian too. How can I resolve this?

Thank in advance.